# How to fetch the target_id for aws_cloudwatch_event_target for a resource created manually from AWS console?

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, terraform-import

As per the Terraform [documentation](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/cloudwatch_event_target#import), the parameters needed for import of `aws_cloudwatch_event_target` are `rule-name/target-id`. If the resource is created manually and now it is to be imported into state file, how can I get the `target-id` from the console?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see `target-id` in the console, however you can retrieve it with the following CLI call:

```bash
$ aws events list-targets-by-rule --rule rule_name
```

Answer (score 1):

EDIT: As mentioned in my comment below, this is sometimes but not always true. I'm leaving this here for reference, however I would recommend using the CLI instead.

I found a reference in the UI after using the command from @paolo and noticing an area that matched. At least, for Lambda Triggers.

In the Lambda Triggers section open the trigger you are wanting and look for "Statement ID". It will have some extra info at the beginning but the UUID at the end matches what the command outputs.

Example:

```
 aws events list-targets-by-rule --rule auto-tag-ec2-creation-events
{
    "Targets": [
        {
            "Id": "Idac6a6268-63a6-4111-aea6-88ba4dfdb4a4",
            "Arn": "arn:aws:lambda:us-west-2:<REDACTED>:function:testtag"
        }
    ]
}
```

[lambda_trigger_section_screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q8xw0.png)

Comment: After importing a few items with this I found that this was true for 2 out of the 3 I was working with. So I'd say trust the CLI as the UI may or may not be accurate.